# contingency table from pandas crosstab on whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, crosstab

I would like to create a condensed contingency table in pandas.
Therefore I started with pandas crosstab, based on clustering from a certain column in the example the decision columns is 'D', e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(4, 3)), columns=list('ABD'))
df
```

[image]

If I want to do crosstab I pass this command:

```
pd.crosstab([df.A,df.B], df.D,  margins=True)
```

Returns the frequency table:

[image]

This is a bit inconvenient for my case.

I would like to do it on a whole dataframe, and not column by column like in the example where I passed a list of columns.
Additionally I would like it to return it in a more condensed way rather than a super huge frequency, like this:

[image]

Any idea how to get there?

Thanks